# Can't locate MLContext

Tags: c#, .net, f#, ml.net

I'm following the ML.Net cookbook "[What if my training data is not in a text file](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/master/docs/code/MlNetCookBook.md#what-if-my-training-data-is-not-in-a-text-file)."

The code includes the line:

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();
```

However, the class `MLContext` is not found. How can I resolve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, ML.Net 0.6 is the released version and does not contain this class. It is available in the [0.7-preview](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-core/package/nuget/Microsoft.ML).

Note [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/1098) related to the reason for and role of MLContext().